# How to call a function from a class that needs "root"

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a script in python that is using multiprocessing. Everything works ok, but I want it to make a bit more complex. In the example below, I don't know how to call a function from the class that needs the root as an argument as the root is defined in another function. I would appreciate some help or advice.

The code that I am using is the following one:

```
import tkinter as tk, time
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
class Example():
    def __init__ (self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, command = self.onStart)
        self.pbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.parent, mode = 'indeterminate', length = 100)
    def pbar_start(self):
        self.pbar.pack()
        self.pbar.start()
    def files(self):
        self.filena = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("comma separated file","*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        return filena
    def onStart():
         self.p1 = Process(target = work)
         self.p1.start()

def work():
    time.sleep(5) # I put time just to show that I don't want the progressbar to start immediately 
    app = Example(root) # here if I call root is giving me an error as expected, but I don't know how I can do it
    app.pbar_start()
    file = app.filena()
    #do some work
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried to place work under the main but it didn't work because when I tried to click the button another window popped up.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot pass tkinter stuff to other process.

Comment: use `global root`, you actually can use neither `multiprocessing` nor `threading` in this particular case, all `tkinter` stuff has to happen in the same process in the same thread

Comment: btw what are you even trying to do? what is the purpose of the `Progressbar`?

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you very much for your comments! Would it work if I use two classes? One Example, for GUI, and one for work()?

Comment: If you still need to access the tkinter stuff inside GUI class from another class in other process, then the answer is still "no".

Comment: @Matiiss I am trying to process some data from a csv file and then plot the data. If I do it without multiprocessing, the GUI is freezing and I don't want that. The Progressbar is just to let the user know that something is happening in the background.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you! That's good to know.

Comment: just pass `root` as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Doesn't work. Because I don't define root in the function afterwards.

Comment: _"Because I don't define root in the function afterwards."_ - then you need to define `root` first, and then pass it into any function that needs it.

Comment: @Tibi `self.parent` of `Example` is the `root`.  However as I said you cannot pass this to `work()` if `work()` is executed in another process.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. I just wanted to try what Bryan suggested.